# Enabling core dumps inside open source GDB code

Tags: gdb, arm

I was looking at the open source GDB code. I wish to write a target dependent code for a processor ( just like ARM and MIPS, etc). I have defined the appropriate files on similar lines. For most cases, my target is able to have GDB working. However, when I try to evaluate core dumps, I get:
This version of GDB does not support core dumping.

This was a check put in the file: target.c

As you know, in GDB we have a strata of types of files that can be debugged. I wanted to know the exact place where ARM/ MIPS or any other processor architecture can enable core dumping.

Thanks

PS: I took a look at opne source arm-linux-tdep.c and arm-tdep.c but could not conclude anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.
As per the GDB documentation, we need to include supply_gregset, etc. routines inside our tdep files. 
Also, in the Makefile.in, we need to include corelow.o to the TARGET_OBS
This ensures that we build GDB to support core dumping